# Why doesn't the nested stack navigation work in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm  a beginner programmer and I'm trying to created a nested navigator in react native.  The stack navigator on the Home screen works but the stack navigator on the MyEvents Screen does not.  I use the tabs to navigate between Home and MyEvents and within the those pages I want to use a stack navigator to get to other pages.  Please help! (also please let me know if I am being unclear)

This is Router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {StackNavigator, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import InputScreen from './InputPage';
import HomeScreen from './Home';
import DetailsScreen from './Details';
import MyEventsScreen from './MyEvents';
import EditScreen from './EditPage';
import MapScreen from './Map';

const BottomNavigation = require('react-native-bottom-navigation');

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  EventMap: {screen: MapScreen},
  Input: {screen: InputScreen},
  MyEvents:{screen: MyEventsScreen},
},{
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColors: '#e91e63',
      //swipeEnabled: true,
    }
});

export const EventsStack = StackNavigator({

  Home: {
    screen: Tabs,
  },
  Details: {
    screen: DetailsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,

    },
  },

});

export const MyEventsStack = StackNavigator({

  MyEvents: {
    screen: Tabs,

    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  MyEventsDetails: {
    screen: EditScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      /*navigation: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `${navigation.state.params.name.first.toUpperCase()} ${navigation.state.params.name.last.toUpperCase()}`,
    }),*/
    },
  },

});


export const Root = StackNavigator({
  TabNav: {
    screen: EventsStack,
  }


}, {headerMode: 'none'});
```

This is Home.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableHighlight,  SectionList} from 'react-native';
import {ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';
import {firebaseApp} from './App';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import {StackNavigator, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {Tabs} from './Router';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
    this.itemsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref().child('items');
    console.ignoredYellowBox = [
         'Setting a timer'
     ];
  }
  onLearnMore = (item) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
      ...item
    });
  };
  static navigationOptions = {
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon
          name = {'Home'}
          size = {26}
          style = {{color: tintColor}} />
      )
  }
  listenForItems(itemsRef) {
    itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      // get children as an array
      var items = [];
      snap.forEach((parent) => {
        var children = [];
        parent.forEach((child) => {
        children.push({
          "name": child.val().name,
          "when": child.val().when,
          "who": child.val().who,
        });
      });
      items.push({
        data: children,
        key: parent.key.toUpperCase(),
      })
      });
      this.setState({
        data: items
      });
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.listenForItems(this.itemsRef);
  }
  render() {
    var styles = require('./Styles');
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Princeton Events</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.body}>
        <SectionList renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem style={styles.item}
            title={item.name} subtitle={item.when}
            onPress={() => this.onLearnMore(item)}/>}
            renderSectionHeader={({section}) =>
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.key}</Text>}
            sections={this.state.data} keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is MyEvents.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableHighlight, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {ListItem, List} from 'react-native-elements';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import Router from './Router';


export default class MyEventsScreen extends Component {
  onViewMyEvent = (item) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Edit', {
      ...item
    });
  };



  static navigationOptions = {
      tabBarLabel: 'MyEvents',
      tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon
          name = {'account circle'}
          size = {26}
          style = {{color: tintColor}} />
      )

  }

  render() {
    var styles = require('./Styles');
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1
      }}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>My Events</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <List containerStyle={{
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            borderBottomWidth: 0
          }}>
            <FlatList data={[
              {
                "name": "Event 1",
                "who": "E-Club",
                "what": "description goes here description goes here description goes here",
                "when": "1:00",
                "where": "Ehub",
                "RSVP": "yes"
              }, {
                "name": "Event 2",
                "who": "Club 2",
                "what": "description goes here",
                "when": "2:00",
                "where": "Location 2",
                "RSVP": "no"
              }
            ]} renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem style={styles.item} title={item.name} subtitle={item.when} containerStyle={{
              borderBottomWidth: 0
            }} onPress={() => this.onViewMyEvent(item)}/>} keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}/>
          </List>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={() => navigate('Home')} underlayColor='#ffd199'>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Back</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your navigators aren't connected properly to do what you want. Take a look at the documentation for [Nesting Navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting). As a starting point, take a look at your `Root` `StackNavigator` and try to trace a path from there to `MyEventsStack`. If you get stuck post again with what you're having trouble understanding.

Comment: Wow thank you! Yes, I realized that MyEventsStack is not connected to anything.  But I'm not sure how to get around this.  Is it possible to nest the two stack navigators in the tab navigator? Any suggestions would be appreciated.